# some tools like lua-check, found out spelling wrong

Tags: lua

Scripting language need not be compiled into exe is good, but often the spelling wrong, like

```
T.abc = 10
```

Written

```
T.abd = 10
```

ABC is a table variable in T, leading to `t.abc` is not correct assignment
Some of the more extreme cases,
Not found out the error `t.abd = 10` in the testing
but found out on product release 
Whether the tool can support this syntax

Comment: I think the OP wants to detect unknown table fields, similar to how lua-check and lua-inspect do this for global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lua-inspect](https://github.com/davidm/lua-inspect) should be able to detect unknown table fields based on dynamic evaluation: "identifies unknown global variables (white-on-red) and table fields (red), inferred by static and dynamic evaluation". [TypedLua](https://github.com/andremm/typedlua) should do this as well, although it's likely to generate more verbose output than Lua-inspect on the same script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a metatable to intercept table access. Try this:

```
local function test(t,k)
    if t[k]==nil then
        error("invalid field "..k)
    end
end

local function newtable(fields)
    return setmetatable({},{
        __index=function (t,k) test(fields,k) end,
        __newindex=function (t,k,v) test(fields,k) rawset(t,k,v) end
    })
end

T=newtable({ abc=true, xyz=true})

print(T.abc)
T.abc = 10
print(T.abc)
T.acb = 10
print(T.acb)
```